# How to connect to a specific database in SQL Server with .NET

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, connection

The code to connect to the database is below, could you tell where I am mistaken?

```
   SqlConnectionStringBuilder setting = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    setting.DataSource = ".\\SQLExpress";
    setting.InitialCatalog = "PCM_NEW";
  //  setting.UserInstance = true;
    setting.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    setting.AttachDBFilename = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\PCM_NEW.mdf";


    //setting.UserID = "LKALAY\\SQLEXPRESS";

    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(setting.ConnectionString);
    return baglanti;
```

I get an error:

> error: provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Comment: What you see an error when you run your code?

Comment: provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Comment: it is what I tried finally. before this,  ı tried \\ intead of ' in order to prevent error which is string mistake because of single slash

Comment: Could you try to remove the UserInstance = true?